# How to use x:class property in Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to pass a View's class name as CommandParameter. How to do this?

```
<UserControl x:Name="window"
             x:Class="Test.Views.MyView"
             ...>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="tabItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.CloseCommand, ElementName=window}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding x:Class, ElementName=window}">
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The result should be a string 'Test.Views.MyView'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[x:Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752309.aspx) is only a directive and not a property so you won't be able to bind to it.

[*From MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752309.aspx)

> Configures XAML markup compilation to join partial classes between
>   markup and code-behind. The code partial class is defined in a
>   separate code file in a Common Language Specification (CLS) language,
>   whereas the markup partial class is typically created by code
>   generation during XAML compilation.

But you can get the same result from the FullName property of the Type. Use a Converter

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=window,
                           Path=.,
                           Converter={StaticResource GetTypeFullNameConverter}}"
```

*GetTypeFullNameConverter*

```
public class GetTypeFullNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return value.GetType().FullName;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I knew I could do it with type converter, I was just curious if its possible without. Anyway, I am already using something similar, I added a string property to ViewModel, which does the same thing (GetType().FullName)